# textAngular inside angular ui modal

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to render an textAngular textarea inside a modal but it won't render, can anyone help me please? I've also tried to insert the code with  but it did not work. The code I've used it below.

```
script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
<div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">Edit Job</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
        <label>Job Title</label>
        <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" id="title" ng-model="form.title" placeholder="Title">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
        <label>Job ID</label>
        <input type="id" name="id" class="form-control" id="id" ng-model="form.id" placeholder="ID">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
        <label>Location</label>
        <input type="location" name="location" class="form-control" id="location" ng-model="form.location" placeholder="Coventry, United Kingdom">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
        <label>Salary</label>
        <input type="salary" name="salary" class="form-control" id="salary" ng-model="form.salary" placeholder="200000">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
        <label>Job Type</label>
        <input type="type" name="type" class="form-control" id="type" ng-model="form.type" placeholder="Type">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
        <label>Job Description</label>
        <text-angular ng-model="form.description"></text-angular>
    </div>
    <br/>

</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
</div>
```

Comment: would you have a plunk or fiddle, by any chance?

Comment: Do you have a Controller for this route? The problem could be somewhere there, not sure why it wouldn't load otherwise

Comment: it has a controller .controller('modalController',['$scope','$http','$rootScope',function($scope,$http,$rootScope) {
        $scope.form={
            title:$rootScope.title,
            id:$rootScope.id,
            location:$rootScope.location,
            salary:$rootScope.salary,
            type:$rootScope.type,
            description:$rootScope.description

}
    }]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably one of three issues:

1. You haven't loaded textAngular in your module, i.e. `angular.module('moduleName', ['textAngular'])`
2. You haven't actually loaded in all the textAngular files.
3. You haven't included `textAngular.css`

Check your console for error messages as well which may give more to go on.

Comment: you were correct, I forgot to load the files in the second page, thanks!